# Search using LIKE Clause Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm tring to convert a Mysql query to using a **LIKE** clause and I can't make it work.

```
$query = "SELECT id,name FROM `hin` WHERE name = '".$q."'";
```

What I've tried in some variations.

```
$query = "SELECT id,name FROM `hin` WHERE name LIKE %'".$q."'%";
```

I need the query to select row only on string match. Intend is to use variable as needle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
"SELECT id,name FROM `hin` WHERE name LIKE '%". $q ."%'"
```

The wildcarding has to be *inside* the single quotes.

Ideally, you want to use:

```
"SELECT id,name FROM `hin` WHERE name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($q) ."%'"
```

Comment: Which is better of the two?